# connecting multiple vm on different machines

Tags: vmware

I have two laptops running windows 10, and vmware workstation 14 installed on both. My objective is to be able to connect from vm A hosted on laptop A to Vm B hosted on Laptop B. note that both laptops are connected to the same router. please advice about the configartion that should be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should connect both laptop together with cable or WiFi(Hot Spot) after that you must use bridge mode on your VMnet in your VMWare Workstation on your laptop and use correct physical interface ( Ethernet or Wireless)
use same subnet for VMs and connect them. 
Note 1: Turn off your Firewall and Third-party firewall software on both Laptop and VMs
Note 2: If and do not make mistake you can change Bridge interface in VMWare Workstation on Edit > Virtual Network Settings